Why do my OpenSCAP scans of a container within a container return "notapplicable" as the results?
I am currently trying to simulate creating a container that scans containers for compliance against DISA STIG profiles. This job will eventually make it into a CI/CD pipeline. Disclaimer here: I am new to DevOps so my responses might not be as knowledgeable as they could be hehe. I am doing this using a MacBook with Docker installed. I created a Redhat/UBI8 docker container and then within that container I installed podman on it and created a container image there using podman pull. I did "podman save" and created a .tar file with it. No matter if I unzip or leave the image as is, I always get the same result after scanning. Each rule returns "notapplicable" as the result. The funny thing is that I know I'm running it with the proper profile. I scanned RHEL8 images, Debian, Ubunutu, and they all return the same.  What could I do to fix this? Should I go about scanning a container within a container a different way?
Steps I took to run the job locally on my Macbook

Please use a codeblock inside your question post which contains the console output of your Macbook (the image you attached) and remove the image itself. This way it is easier to grasp the problem you describe. Additionally, highlight the lines in the output where you expect a different result - because they are failing.
